# How can I use record content from one table to update another, without a join option?

Tags: sql, sql-server

### I need to update values in a column in a specific table that exists in all our databases, but do not know the name of the column as it is user-generated.

I have two tables: one of them with user-generated columns *tab_Case*. In this table there is a column *attachment* that I need to update if the following condition applies: WHERE attachment = '0' (if true then the value needs to be changed to NULL). 
In its simplest form the update query would look something like this:

```
UPDATE tab_Case
SET attachment = 'NULL'
WHERE attachment = '0'
```

This table is used in all our databases, so I need to write a query general enough to be usable across all of them.
The problem is that as the table uses user-generated columns, I have no way of knowing what the exact name is of concerned column-type, and exactly how many of those columns exist in the table.

I can, however, find out the type of the column by looking it up in another table *tbl_itemPart* inner joined with *tbl_ValueType*, like this:

```
SELECT ip.DbReference, ip.DbTableName, vt.ValueDescription
FROM tbl_itemPart ip
INNER JOIN tbl_ValueTypes vt ON ip.ValueTypeId = vt.ValuetypeId
WHERE vt.ValueDescription = 'file'
AND ip.DbTableName = 'tab_Case'
```

The columns I need are always of type 'file' and as the *tab_Case* table is referenced in *tbl_ItemPart* it is easy to find out **1)** if any columns of type 'file'  exist in this table, and **2)** when true, what their respective names are.

So great, now I know the names of the columns that I need to potentially update. But, this is where I get lost: how do I use that information in my update query?

How do I write a script that first checks the *tbl_itemPart* for existence of any columns in *tab_Case* of type ' file', then retrieves the actual values (= names of those columns) from the *DbReference* column in *tbl_itemPart* and then finally uses those values in the update query for *tab_Case*? 
Remember that this scripts needs to automatically do this for each of our databases, so I do *not* want to look up column names manually per database and then adjust my script accordingly for each of the databases.

I am very new to programming, and may be missing something very obvious, but so far I haven't been able to find a solution, or any relevant information to help me on my way.

Comment: You need to build a update statement based on the results of the query you have provided. This is referred to as dynamic SQL.

Comment: You are struggling here because the system you are working on is using an antipattern known as entity value attribute (EAV). It is seriously painful to work with. Don't get me wrong there are times it makes sense, but for everything...not so much.

Comment: There are lots of resources online in regard to dynamic SQL. Here is one... https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

Comment: dynamic SQL .... that is indeed new to me, I will do some research online. Thanks for the help @isaac

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for your comment, this also requires a little more research on my part, will certainly look into it!

Comment: [Here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/?article=292) is a fun article about an extreme case of EAV. :)